# Can anyone make sense of this sentense?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

It is a headline on NY Times:

> ‘Candyman’ Review: Who Can Take a Sunrise, Sprinkle It With Blood?"

"Who Can Take a Sunrise, Sprinkle It With Blood" what does author mean by that?

The comma is getting me confused, can I replace the comma for "AND"??

Comment: Yes, you should replace the comma by “and.” Headlines are written in an abbreviated style to save space and should not be used as models of normal English. And this headline would not make **ANY** sense to anyone not familiar with the movie.

Comment: I'm sure Candyman is a horror movie. Perhaps featuring vampires, who are very much into blood, *and* have a curious relationship with ***dawn's early light*** (it kills them). The syntax of headlines is minimal to non-existent, so there's no point in thinking about "improving" it.

Comment: @Jeff: in this case I would emphatically say you **cannot** replace the comma with "and," because then it would not match the song lyric it's referencing. And the headline made sense to me even though I haven't seen the movie (the same as most of the readers of this review, I would guess)—because I know about the song.

Comment: @randomhead The OP was asking about meaning, not whether the headline tracked the lyrics of a song. I am quite sure that you are correct that most readers under a certain age would be annoyed by a misquotation, but the OP did not understand the exact quotation.

Comment: @Jeff: a fair point, but I would say the author "means" to make a reference to the song lyric. Substituting the "and" might help to explain the song lyric but is less helpful in explaining the headline, because the headline is deliberately written the way it is to match something else. Usually I would agree with you that headline writers use the comma instead of "and" to save space, and substituting it can help; in this case that is *not* true because of the song reference. If that isn't too confusing.

Comment: @randomhead No, it is not too confusing. And you are right that my implied criticism of the writer of the headline was wrong. But the OP was just as benighted culturally as I was, and neither headlines nor song lyrics are a great way to learn standard English. Sorry for the curtness of my previous response.

Answer (score 3):

This is a reference to a song, called "[The Candyman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPIl0IJjBrw)" From *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory (1971)* (and not related to the horror film)

> Who can take a sunrise,
> Sprinkle it in dew,
> Cover it in chocolate
> and a miracle or two?
> The candyman!
> The candyman can.

The song has the form of a list of things that the owner of the candy store can do.

But for the headline about a horror film, the lyric has been changed to make it horrific.  Grammatically you could use "and", but that would then not reference the song so well.